# Group multiple exports in a single group in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I can have some code like this:

```
- file1.ts
export const FOO...
export const BAR...
```

Then I can do this in another file:

```
- file2.ts
import * as CONSTANTS from './file1/.ts'
export { CONSTANTS };
```

This way, in any file I could use this:

```
import { CONSTANTS } from './file2.ts'
...
let variable = CONSTANTS.foo ...
```

My question is, can I achieve the same thing without the `file2.ts`? I mean, export the members as a group from the same file where they're defined. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

```
// file1.ts
export namespace Constants {
    export const FOO = ...;
    export const BAR = ...;
}
```

Now `file1` is a module with a single exported namespace (js object) with properties `FOO` and `BAR`.

```
import { Constants } from './file1.ts'
let variable = Constants.FOO;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had used this approach without using namespaces:

```
- file1.ts
const Foo...
const Bar...

export const Constants = {
  Foo,
  Bar,
}
```

```
- fileY.ts
import { Constants } from './file1.ts'

Constants.Foo()
```